# created one user defined metrics with which an alert is generated every time a firewall is created/modified/deleted but alert automatically recovers

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created one user defined metrics with which an alert is generated every time a firewall is created/modified/deleted.

[image]

and configured the alert

[image]

Alerts get triggered and incident is generated but after some time alert automatically cleared with email "Alert recovered". I dont want the alert to be cleared automatically but should be there for ops team to investigate and acknowledge.

Please suggest what is missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate events over period of time, e.g. a day; But then it will only trigger on first occurrence.
The best solution, I think, is to edit the alerting policy and uncheck **"Notify on incident resolution"**.
Incidents will be resolved, but ops team can still check them via link in the e-mail.

If you think that function should be available, you can file a Feature Request at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).